# Restoring household_objects_database

Tags: ros, household-objects-database

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to connect **household_objects_database** to **object_recognition_kitchen** in ROS Hydro. I'm following this tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/household_objects_database/Tutorials/Install%20the%20household_objects%20database%20on%20your%20local%20database%20server). I've tried to *restore* the database from several backup files, but it never works.

For example, *household_objects-experimental.backup* gives:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 430; 1247 26713 TYPE model_result willow
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  type "model_result" already exists
    Command was: CREATE TYPE model_result AS (
    f1 text,
    f2 text,
    f3 double precision,
    f4 double precision,
    f5 double precision
);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196426/restoring-household_objects_database/) by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 529 on 2014-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sounds more like a postgres question. Perhaps their documentation will be helpful? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-droptype.html

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2014-11-03**:
I guess I restored it on one computer. How do I use the models now? The documentation seems to be brief ...

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-11-03**:
I can't really help you interpret the models. The best I can do is point you at the message documentation: http://docs.ros.org/groovy/api/object_manipulation_msgs/html/index-msg.html